# Functions to have expected to have a maximum of 5 parameters

Tags: f#

I know that it is a just a style guide, but what do you do with functions with long parameters list:

```
let getItemsChunk orgid1 orgid2 orgid3 (asutpid : int) id tmp1 
                  (mgroup : int) (itemtype : int) t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 pid2 itemdesc model 
                  issuedate address manufacturer shorttype3 (status : int)
                  (offset : int) (chunk : int) : Item[] =
```

**Update:**

All this function is REST API for web service:

```
   [<OperationContract>]
   [<WebGet(UriTemplate  = "ItemsByOrganizationAndParent/{orgid1}/{orgid2}/{orgid3}/{asutpid}/{id}/{tmp1}/{mgroup}/{itemtype}/{t1}/{t2}/{t3}/{t4}/{t5}/{pid2}/{itemdesc}/{model}/{issuedate}/{address}/{manufacturer}/{shorttype3}/{status}/{offset}/{chunk}", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)>]
   abstract GetItemsByOrganizationAndParent: orgid1: string * orgid2: string * orgid3: string * asutpid: string * id: string * tmp1: string * mgroup: string * itemtype: string * t1: string * t2: string * t3: string * t4: string * t5: string * pid2: string * itemdesc: string * model: string * issuedate: string * address: string * manufacturer: string * shorttype3:string * status:string * offset: string * chunk: string -> ItemResponse
```

Each of such functions construct SQL query and return data to the browser asa JSON:

```
let getItemsChunk orgid1 orgid2 orgid3 (asutpid : int) id tmp1 (mgroup : int) (itemtype : int) t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 pid2 itemdesc model issuedate address manufacturer shorttype3 (status : int) (offset : int) (chunk : int) : Item[] =

        let offset : int = offset * chunk 
        let chunk = if noCountGrid = "true" then chunk + 1 else chunk                    
        let sql = ItemSql()

        try
            use db = new dbml.MobileDataContext(connectionString)
            db.ExecuteCommand(readUncommitted) |> ignore

            let issueDateTime = match issuedate with
                                | "0" -> DateTime.MinValue
                                | _ -> DateTime.ParseExact(issuedate, "dd.MM.yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)  

            let command = query {
                for rows in db.Item do
                where (
                        (orgid1   = "0"  || rows.OrgId1 = orgid1) &&
                        (orgid2   = "0"  || rows.OrgId2 = orgid2) &&
                        (orgid3   = "0"  || rows.OrgId3 = orgid3) &&
                        (asutpid  = 0    || rows.AsutpAutoId = asutpid) &&                        
                        (id       = "0"  || rows.Sn.Contains(id)) &&
                        (tmp1     = "0"  || rows.TMP1.Contains(tmp1)) &&
                        (mgroup   = 0    || rows.MaintenanceGroupId = mgroup) &&
                        (itemtype = 0    || rows.ItemType = itemtype) &&
                        (t1       = "0"  || rows.TypeId1 = t1) &&
                        (t2       = "0"  || rows.TypeId2 = t2) &&
                        (t3       = "0"  || rows.TypeId3 = t3) &&
                        (t4       = "0"  || rows.TypeId4 = t4) &&
                        (t5       = "0"  || rows.TypeId5 = t5) &&
                        (pid2     = "-1" || rows.ParentId2 = pid2) &&

                        (itemdesc      = "0"  || rows.Itemdescription = itemdesc) &&
                        (model         = "0"  || rows.Model = model) &&
                        (issuedate     = "0"  || rows.Issuedate = issueDateTime) &&
                        (address       = "0"  || rows.Address = address) &&
                        (manufacturer  = "0"  || rows.Manufacturer = manufacturer) &&
                        (shorttype3    = "0"  || rows.ShortType3Description = shorttype3) &&
                        (status        = 0    || rows.Status = (statusFoo status))
                      )

                sortBy rows.AutoincrementedId 
                select rows
                skip offset
                take chunk
            }

            match withRecompile with 
            | "true" -> 
                use connection = db.Connection
                connection.Open()
                use cmd = db.GetCommand(command)
                cmd.CommandText <- cmd.CommandText + " OPTION (RECOMPILE)"
                use reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                let newcommand = db.Translate<dbml.Item>(reader)
                let result = newcommand |> Seq.toArray |> Array.map sql.Record2Item
                connection.Close()
                result
            | _ -> 
                command
                |> (fun s ->
                        if Seq.isEmpty s then
                            [||]
                        else
                            s |>  Seq.map sql.Record2Item |> Seq.toArray)
        with
            | exn -> logException exn 
                     [||]
```

Comment: That's what records are for.

Comment: As I know there is no anonymous record in F#, so I need to declare record for each method.  This is not look like a best solution :(

Comment: What I'm saying here is that if you find yourself in such a situation, there's clearly a problem in how you represent your data. It's hard for me to imagine that you have a function with 23 arguments that don't form a few cohesive entities.

Comment: If you're looking for more concrete advice, post more of the context. We don't know what the function does, what the arguments stand for, or where they come from.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Then you want to be using a type provider like http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html, which will construct appropriate types for you on-the-fly.

Comment: I've never seen a truly RESTful API like that... A style guide can sometimes uncover architectural problems, which is what I guess is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a truly RESTful API like that... A style guide can sometimes uncover architectural problems, which is what I guess is happening here.

Comment: But what is the solution ?